# Parse Cloud Code query not getting executed

Tags: objective-c, macos, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have the below cloud code function and when I call this function from my OS X app, I get the success response as well. But none of the console log output messages inside the success and failure blocks of the query operation gets executed. Any ideas on where to look would be much appreciated.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("markAlertAsExpired", function(request, response) {

  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var Alert = Parse.Object.extend("Alert");
  var query = new Parse.Query(Alert);
  query.get("vC6ppoxuqd", {
    success: function(alertObj) {
      // The object was retrieved successfully.
      var status = alertObj.get("status");
      console.log("RECEIVED OBJECT WITH STATUS:");
      console.log(status);
      if (status == "active") {
        console.log("active");
        markActiveAlertAsExpired(alertObj);
      } else if (status == "inactive") {
        console.log("inactive");
        markInactiveAlertAsExpired(alertObj);
      } else {
        console.error("unknown_status");
      }
    },
    error: function(object, error) {
      // The object was not retrieved successfully.
      // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
      console.error("alert_not_found");
      response.error("alert_not_found");
    }
  });

  response.success("available");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for your queries to complete before calling response.success, the updated code below should work.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("markAlertAsExpired", function(request, response) {

  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var Alert = Parse.Object.extend("Alert");
  var query = new Parse.Query(Alert);
  query.get("vC6ppoxuqd", {
    success: function(alertObj) {
      // The object was retrieved successfully.
      var status = alertObj.get("status");
      console.log("RECEIVED OBJECT WITH STATUS:");
      console.log(status);
      if (status == "active") {
        console.log("active");
        markActiveAlertAsExpired(alertObj);
      } else if (status == "inactive") {
        console.log("inactive");
        markInactiveAlertAsExpired(alertObj);
      } else {
        console.error("unknown_status");
      }
      response.success("available");
    },
    error: function(object, error) {
      // The object was not retrieved successfully.
      // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
      console.error("alert_not_found");
      response.error("alert_not_found");
    }
  });


});
```